# Understanding JavaScript Function that Returns 2 Values

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following function that finds the greatest common divisor of 2 integers. I don't understand what's happening in the return greatestCommonDivisor(b, (a % b)); part.

If I do greatestCommonDivisor(8, 12) I get 4 which is right but when I tried to evaluate the return greatestCommonDivisor(b, (a % b)); part I get (12, (8 % 12)) which simplifies to (12, 0) how does this equal 4?

```
// Finds greatest common divisor
function greatestCommonDivisor(a, b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }

    return greatestCommonDivisor(b, (a % b));
}
```

Comment: `8 % 12` is `8` (not `0`), so the next call is `greatestCommonDivisor(12, 8)`. Then you have `(8, 12 % 8)` which is `(8, 4)`, etc. until `b` is `0` and `a` is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is using recursion to call itself until it meets a base condition which returns your actual answer.

In the case of `greatestCommonDivisor(8, 12)` the following occurs:

1. b != 0 so call greatestCommonDivisor(12, 8 % 12) //8 % 12 = 8
2. b != 0 so call greatestCommonDivisor(8, 12 % 8) // 12 % 8 = 4
3. b != 0 so call greatestCommonDivisor(4, 8 % 4) // 8 % 4 = 0
4. b == 0 so return 4

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive function. It doesn't return two values, it returns `a` after calling itself over and over with different (smaller) arguments, until `b` equals `0` (meaning, you can't divide or take a modulus anymore).

Comment: Until `b == 0`, actually. :)

Comment: Should be, I concur, but 'taint.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic algorithm to find out the greatest common divisor between two numbers.

The function returns a call to itself with two other parameters, not returns two values (b, (a%b)) as you thought :)